# How to remove <li> list items and make the remaining ones change their position and id?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Tricky question and far too advanced for my level (js student).

Lets say I use the append method to generate `<li>` items inside an `<ol>`, and I need each one of those li items to have a unique id, so I thought to get the amount of `<li>` (length) items I generated by saying this : `var index = document.getElementById("ol1").getElementsByTagName("li").length+1;` and use this number to create unique id's for every item I generate by doing this: `li.id="li"+index;` so the first one I generate becomes #**li1** (since the amount of li items is one), the next one **#li2** and so on. *btw, is it the right approach to do this?

Now lets say I want to remove #li1, then #li2 would replace it in position 1 of the list, but its id will still be #li2 since it has gotten it already.

For example what I ultimately want is when I remove #li1, then #li2 becomes #li1, #li3 becomes #li2, #li4 becomes #li3.....and so on.

What would be the right logic approach to do such a gimmick?

```js
function append() {

  var index = document.getElementById("ol1").getElementsByTagName("li").length + 1;


  var ol = document.getElementById("ol1");
  var li = document.createElement("li");

  li.id = "li" + index;
  li.innerHTML = (`LIST ITEM <input value=this&nbsp;is&nbsp;id:&nbsp;#li${index}><button class=remove id= button${index} onclick=remove${index}()>REMOVE</button>`);
  ol.append(li)


}

function remove1() {
  var rem = document.getElementById("li1");
  rem.remove();
}

function displayIndex() {
  var index = document.getElementById("ol1").getElementsByTagName("li").length;

  alert(index);
}
```

```css
#li1 {
  color: red;
}

#li2 {
  color: green;
}

#li3 {
  color: blue;
}

ol button {
  color: red;
  visibility: hidden;
}

#button1 {
  color: red;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <button id="btn1" onclick="append()">Append</button>
  <button id="btn2" onclick="displayIndex()">Index</button>
</head>

<body>
  <ol id="ol1">
  </ol>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Nothing should be in the `head` of your document except `title`, `script`, `link`, `meta`, and a few other tags that don't display anything. `button` is right out. If you want, you can add a `header` element to your `body`, but that's different.

Comment: You could just update all IDs whenever the delete button is pressed, but the bigger question is why you'd want to do this anyway? You can always get a fresh array of elements in order in JS at any point and get the element at a specific location without ID, and you can target each element by their position in the list with CSS using :nth-of-type. You shouldn't really be applying styles by ID.

Comment: @t-jam I've checked the selector you mentioned.and even though i was'nt doing this for applying styles the whole concept of nth-of-type looks like a solution for the reason i am trying to do all this.
What i want is to connect the first,or the second or the third item(and so on) of a list to some other parts of the page,and i want to get their values somehow to do some stuff with it,thats why i wanted their unique id's,its the farthest my knowledge goes at this point
could i use this selector with plain js or jquery to target specific  items in specific positions of a list ?

Comment: Well you could use something like `document.querySelectorAll('#ol1 li')[0]` to get the first `li` element. Does that do the trick?

In jQuery you you do something like `$('#ol1 li').eq(0)` to do the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

First off:
There are no "right" approaches. Only working implementations. *How* it is achieved might differ from developer to developer, and as long as it works, it should be considered the "right" way (however, not necessarily the most efficient or optimized or any other way).

One way would be to use a `remove()` function that re-assigns the ID's of the remaining `<li>`s (after the removal, obviously) as a side-effect.

```js
function removeItemOf(list, listItem) {
  if (!list.contains(listItem)) return;
  
  listItem.remove();
  indexItemsOf(list);
  
  // For displaying the removed ID on-screen
  document.querySelector('div').append(
    document.createElement('br'),
    document.createTextNode(`Removed <li> with id '${listItem.id}'`)
  );
}

function indexItemsOf(list) {
  for (var i = 0; list.children[i]; ++i) {
    list.children[i].id = (list.id || list.tagName) + '-li' + i;
    
    // For displaying the <li>'s ID on-screen
    list.children[i].textContent = `With ID '${list.children[i].id}'`;
  }
}

var list = document.querySelector('ol');

indexItemsOf(list);
setTimeout(() => {
  removeItemOf(list, list.children[0]);
}, 2000);
setTimeout(() => {
  removeItemOf(list, list.children[1]);
}, 4000);
```

```html
<ol>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ol>

<div></div>
```

However, re-assigning a previously used ID makes it not unique to one element, as it now identifies another element it hasn't identified before. For environments where this would be important (e.g. relying on an element to reference certain other elements, or to have a certain event-listener, etc.), re-using an ID would break the environment.

To circumvent this problem, one could keep track of how many unique items a list had over its entire lifetime, and create the next item with an ID using that amount, and then increase the amount by one.

Here is an example:

```js
var list = document.querySelector('ol');
list.uniqueItems = 0;

// Here: Using Event-Delegation for removing a <li>
list.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
  if (evt.target.classList.contains('btn-delete'))
    evt.target.closest('li').remove();
});

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var item = document.createElement('li');
  item.id = 'li-' + list.uniqueItems;
  item.textContent = `Has the ID '${item.id}' `;
  
  var btnDelete = document.createElement('button');
  btnDelete.classList.add('btn-delete');
  btnDelete.textContent = 'Delete Item';
  
  item.append(btnDelete);
  list.append(item);
  
  list.uniqueItems++;
});
```

```html
<button>New Item</button>

<ol></ol>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just loop through each list item after your remove one and regenerate the IDs for each.

```js
ol = document.getElementById("ol1");

function indexLIs(){
  i = 1;
  ol.querySelectorAll("li").forEach(function(li){
     id = "li" + i;
     li.setAttribute("id",id);
     li.querySelector("input").value = "this is id: #" + id;
     i++;
  });
}

function append() {

  var index = document.getElementById("ol1").getElementsByTagName("li").length + 1;


  var li = document.createElement("li");

  li.id = "li" + index;
  li.innerHTML = (`LIST ITEM <input value=this&nbsp;is&nbsp;id:&nbsp;#li${index}><button class=remove id= button${index} onclick=remove${index}()>REMOVE</button>`);
  ol.append(li)


}

function remove1() {
  var rem = document.getElementById("li1");
  rem.remove();
  indexLIs();
}

function displayIndex() {
  var index = document.getElementById("ol1").getElementsByTagName("li").length;

  alert(index);
}
```

```css
#ol1 li:nth-child(1) {
  color: red;
}

#ol1 li:nth-child(2) {
  color: green;
}

#ol1 li:nth-child(3) {
  color: blue;
}

ol button {
  color: red;
  visibility: hidden;
}

#button1 {
  color: red;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <button id="btn1" onclick="append()">Append</button>
  <button id="btn2" onclick="displayIndex()">Index</button>
</head>

<body>
  <ol id="ol1">
  </ol>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is fine. It would be easier for you to keep counting from the last element without changing the other elements even if you remove an element. In that situation use a global variable and initialize it with the length of your initial list. Something like that should do the work:

```
var index = 1; // or the index you wish to start from
function append(){
  
var ol = document.getElementById("ol1");
var li = document.createElement("li");
  
  li.id="li"+index;
  li.innerHTML = (`LIST ITEM <input value=this&nbsp;is&nbsp;id:&nbsp;#li${index}><button class=remove id= button${index} onclick=remove${index}()>REMOVE</button>`);
  ol.append(li);
  // now we will increment our index for the next iteration
  index++;

}
```

Hope this was useful.